# How to add subviews programmatically in nsscrollview - cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

In my cocoa application, i want to add subviews(NSView)dynamically in nsscrollview.

I have tried this in my implementation:

```
  NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, yOrigin, 200, 50)];

    view.layer.backgroundColor = [[NSColor blueColor] CGColor];

    [self.chatScrollView setDocumentView: view];
```

But i didn't noticed any changes in my application. Can anyone please suggest an answer to accomplish the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look, I think you just need setWantslayer.  Add the following to the 2nd row.

```
[view setWantsLayer:YES];
```